# Limit and Continuity of $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+|nx|}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

how do I calculate the limit of the following function and show that it is a continuous function?
$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+|nx|}$
when $f_n: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $x \in \Bbb R$

I know that

$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N\in\mathbb{N}: \exists n\geq N : \exists x \in \Bbb R: |\,f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$

and I must calculate $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$, but I definitely can't go further...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that for $x\ne 0$ given you have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{nx}{1+|nx|}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{x}{1/n+|x|}=\frac{x}{|x|}=\begin{cases}1, & x>0,\\-1, &x<0.\end{cases}$$

It must be obvious that $\lim_n f_n(0)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, then the limit is $0$. If $x\ne 0$, then $f_n(x)\to \frac{x}{|x|}$, so the limit function is the signum function. Because it is discontinuous, the convergence is not uniform, pointwise only.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$f_n $ is an odd function.
we will assume $x\ge 0$.

$\lim_{+\infty}f_n(0)=0=f (0)$

and if $x>0$,

$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {nx}{nx+1}=1=f (x)$

the limit function is not continuous at $x=0$.